# Slicing in C++ where I am wrong?

Tags: c++, inheritance, object-slicing

I read about the slicing problem in C++ and I tried some examples (I am from Java background). Unfortunatelly, I do not understand some of the behaviour. Currently, I am stucked in this example (alternated example from Efficent C++ Third Edition). Can anybody help me to understand it?

My simple class of a parent:

```
class Parent
{
public:

    Parent(int type) { _type = type; }

    virtual std::string getName() { return "Parent"; }

    int getType() { return _type; }

private:

    int _type;
};
```

My simple class of a Child:

```
class Child : public Parent
{

public:

    Child(void) : Parent(2) {};

    virtual std::string getName() { return "Child"; }
    std::string extraString() { return "Child extra string"; }
};
```

The main:

```
void printNames(Parent p)
{
    std::cout << "Name: " << p.getName() << std::endl;

    if (p.getType() == 2)
    {
        Child & c = static_cast<Child&>(p);
        std::cout << "Extra: " << c.extraString() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Name after cast: " << c.getName() << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Parent p(1);
    Child c;

    printNames(p);
    printNames(c);
}
```

Afte the execution I get:

**Name: Parent**

**Name: Parent**

**Extra: Child extra string**

**Name after cast: Parent**

I understand the first two lines, because it is the cause of the "slicing". But I do not understand why can I cast the child into parent via the static cast. In the book, there is written that after the slicing, all the specialized information will be sliced off. So I suppose, I cannot cast **p** into **c**, because I do not have infomation (in the beginning of the function printNames a new Parent object is created without the additional information).

Additionaly, why I am getting the "Name after cast: Parent" if the cast was successful instead of "Name after cast: Child"?

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you had posted just the bit that you _actually_ don't understand, not your whole code.

Comment: `Child & c = static_cast<Child&>(p);` thats a good route to UB

Comment: "So I suppose, I cannot cast p into c, because I do not have infomation" - that's a wrong assumption. You **can** cast because `static_cast`ing is a compile-time thing `Child` is a subtype of `Parent`, so the compiler permits this. However, at runtime (choosing the right virtual method is a *runtime* problem), the lost information will prevent the actual execution of the overriding method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your result is an extraordinary stroke of bad luck. This is the result I’m getting:

```
Name: Parent
Name: Parent
Extra: Child extra string
bash: line 8:  6391 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./a.out
```

Here’s what’s happening in your code:

When you pass `c` to `printNames`, a *conversion* takes place. In particular, since the pass is by value, you invoke the copy constructor of `Parent`, which is implicitly declared and whose code would look like this:

```
Parent(Parent const& other) : _type{other._type} {}
```

In other words, you copy the `_type` variable of `c` *and nothing else*. You now have a *new* object of type `Parent` (both its static and dynamic type are `Parent`) and `c` isn’t actually passed into `printNames` at all.

Inside the function, you then forcefully convert `p` to a `Child&`. This cast cannot succeed because `p` simply isn’t a `Child`, or convertible to one, but C++ doesn’t give you any diagnostic for that (which is actually a shame, since the compiler could trivially prove that the cast is wrong).

Now we’re in the land of undefined behaviour and now everything is allowed to happen. In practice, since `Child::extraString` never accesses `this` (either implicitly or explicitly), the call to that function just succeeds. The call is done on an illegal object but since the object is never touched, that works (but is still illegal!).

The next call, to `Child::getName`, is a virtual call and thus it needs to explicitly access `this` (in most implementations, it accesses the virtual method table pointer). And again, because the code is UB anyway, anything can happen. You were “lucky” and the code just grabbed the virtual method table pointer of the parent class. With my compiler, that access obviously failed.

Comment: And this, my friends, is why you simply cannot learn C++ by trial and error.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, now it is much cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

That code's horrific.  What's happening:

- `printNames(c)` slices `c`, copy-constructing local `p` from the `Parent` object embedded in the caller's `c` object, then setting `p`'s pointer to the `Parent` virtual dispatch table.
- because the data members of `Parent` were copied from `c`, the type of `p` is 2 and the `if` branch is entered
- `Child & c = static_cast<Child&>(p);` effectively tells the compiler "trust me (I'm a programmer) and I know that `p` is actually a `Child` object that I'd like a reference to", but that's a blatant lie as `p` is actually a `Parent` object copied from the `Child` `c`

  - the onus is on you as the programmer to not ask the compiler to do this if you're not sure it's valid
- `c.extraString()` is found statically (at compile time) by the compiler because it knows `c` is a `Child` (or further derived type, but `c.extraString` isn't `virtual` so it can be resolved statically; it's ***undefined behaviour*** to do this on a `Parent` object, but probably because `extraString` doesn't try to access any data that only a `Child` object would have, it has ostensibly run "ok" for you
- `c.getName()` is `virtual`, so the compiler uses the object's virtual dispatch table - because the object is really a `Parent` it resolves dynamically (at run time) to the `Parent::getName` function and produces the associated output

  - the implementation of virtual dispatch is implementation defined though, and your undefined behaviour might not happen to function this way on all C++ implementations, or even at all optimisation levels, with all compiler options etc.